# Stripe react native google pay what's the merchantName?

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, google-pay

I am implementing Google Pay using stripe, also i have created google pay account. I seen one parameter and that i don't have that value.

`merchantName` what is the merchantName, i have merchantID that i found on google pay account, how can i get merchantName? can anyone help me in this case?

this is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GooglePayButton, useGooglePay } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import { Alert, View } from 'react-native';
import { showMessage } from 'react-native-flash-message';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';


const GooglePayPayment = ({ pricingDetails }) => {
    const { currency, id, price } = pricingDetails;
    const {
        isGooglePaySupported,
        initGooglePay,
        createGooglePayPaymentMethod
    } = useGooglePay();


    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    useEffect(() => {
        if (!(isGooglePaySupported({ testEnv: false }))) {
            showMessage({
                message: 'Google Pay is not supported.',
                type: 'danger',
            });
            return;
        }

        const { error } = initGooglePay({

            testEnv: false,
            merchantName: 'BCR2DN4TQSDRTDFD',
            countryCode: 'CH',
            billingAddressConfig: {
                format: 'FULL',
                isPhoneNumberRequired: true,
                isRequired: false,
            },
            existingPaymentMethodRequired: false,
            isEmailRequired: true,
        });

        if (error) {
            // DO SOMETHING HERE
            return;
        }
    }, []);

    const googlePaymentMethod = async () => {
        const { error, paymentMethod } = await createGooglePayPaymentMethod({
            amount: parseFloat(price),
            currencyCode: currency?.toUpperCase(),
        });

        if (error) {
            showMessage({
                message: `${error.code, error.message}`,
                type: 'danger',
            });
            return;
        } else if (paymentMethod) {
           // do something here

        }
    };




    return (
        <View>
            <GooglePayButton

                type="standard"
                onPress={googlePaymentMethod}
                style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 40,
                    marginTop: 5
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default GooglePayPayment;
```

Please have a look at above code, you will notice a parmater named `MerchantID`, i want to know, what will be it's value?

I tried with merchantID, but i doesn't work. i want to implement in react native for google pay with MerchantName,

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Pay with Stripe you don't need to create a Google Pay account or have a Merchant ID. Stripe takes care of that for you. All you need to do is to pass in the `merchantName` (your business name) which will be displayed in the Google pay popup. You can read more about integrating Google Pay with react-native [here](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=react-native).